# How to create a shell script with the systemctl

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu, shell

I've been trying to create a script but it doesn't work out, if you can help me ...

I'm doing a script on the systemctl command that should ask you to write the name of a service, and then show you the status of that service. If the service does not exist, it should show you an error message saying that the service does not exist.

```
read -p "Write the name of service : " systemctl

if 
systemctl "$service"
then
echo $service
else
echo "Don't exist the service"
fi
```

And I get this error

```
Write the name of service: colord.service 
Unknown operation .
Don't exist the service
```

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, why would you write a script for this? The `systemctl` command already does it for you:

```
$ systemctl status atd.service | head
● atd.service - Deferred execution scheduler
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/atd.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2020-10-04 14:15:04 EEST; 3h 56min ago
       Docs: man:atd(8)
    Process: 2390931 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/find /var/spool/atd -type f -name =* -not -newercc /run/systemd -delete (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 2390932 (atd)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 38354)
     Memory: 2.8M
     CGroup: /system.slice/atd.service
             └─2390932 /usr/bin/atd -f
```

And, when you give it a service that doesn't exist:

```
$ systemctl status foo.service 
Unit foo.service could not be found.
```

So it looks like it can already do what you need. Regardless, in order to do whjat your script was attempting, you need to change your `read`:

```bsh
read -p "Write the name of service : " systemctl
```

That will read whatever you type into the variable `$systemctl`. But you never use that variable. Instead, you use:

```bsh
systemctl "$service"
```

Since you have never defined `$service`, that is an empty string, so you are just running:

```
$ systemctl ""
Unknown command verb .
```

What you want to do, is something like this:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
read -p "Write the name of service : " service

if 
  systemctl | grep -q "$service"
then
  systemctl status "$service"
else
  echo "The service doesn't exist"
fi
```

Or, since it is almost always better to pass arguments on the command line instead of having your users type them (if you type, it's easy to make a mistake, the full command doesn't appear in history, you cannot automate it, just don't type):

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

service=$1
if 
  systemctl | grep -q "$service"
then
  systemctl status "$service"
else
  echo "The service doesn't exist"
fi
```

And then run:

```
foo.sh colord.service
```